# How to write tests inside loop?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I'm trying to write a dynamic test that looks like this:

```
let a = []
describe(`Testing`, () => {
    before(() => {
        a = [1,2,3,4,5]
    });
    it('first', (done) => {
        expect(a[0]).to.equal(1);
    
        done();
    });
    a.forEach(value => {
        it(`should return ${ value }+1`, () => {
          expect(value).to.be.eql(value);
        })
      });

});
```

The first test runs completely OK and `a` array is accessible inside the test, but when I try to loop over `a` and run tests, `a` is empty.

Comment: You can't. The tests and hooks are registered at _discovery_ time, at which point `a = []`. The values `[1,2,3,4,5]` aren't set until _execution_ time. Note that you don't actually seem to be using [tag:jestjs], but Jest, Mocha and other test runners have the same behaviour here.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Can you please provide me a link to the documentation, I want to read more about this discovery and execution phases.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with the timing - execution of the `forEach` block.

It has a synchronous nature due to which it is considering an empty array that you have initialized at the start of your code.

`jest` and any other testing framework has an asynchronous nature which means it is non-blocking.

Therefore the code execution will progress to the next block which is your `forEach` loop that currently has an empty `a[]` array reference.

Including the forEach loop inside the describe block will get you the required result.

```js
describe('Testing', () => {
  let a;

  before(() => {
    a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  });

  it('first', (done) => {
    expect(a[0]).to.equal(1);
    done();
  });

  a.forEach((value) => {
    it(`should return ${value}+1`, () => {
      expect(value + 1).to.be.eql(value + 1);
    });
  });
});
```

Edit: To dynamically generate test cases based on an array, you can use a loop within the beforeEach hook to define the test cases individually.

```js
describe('Testing', () => {
  let a;

  before(() => {
    a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  });

  it('first', (done) => {
    expect(a[0]).to.equal(1);
    done();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    a.forEach((value) => {
      it(`should return ${value}+1`, () => {
        expect(value + 1).to.be.eql(value + 1);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

- By using beforeEach instead of before, the test cases will be generated before each test, ensuring that the array values are correctly processed for each test case.

Comment: Yes , I have realized that but I couldn't find any solutions.

Comment: If you include the `forEach` block inside the describe block then that should work. I edited the answer above to highlight that. If you want I can include the code block but I guess it will be easy. [edit: included a snippet rearranging your code]

Comment: The code runs with a.forEach being undefined

Comment: Hey, sorry I didn’t test this code - let me try to check it post work and I’ll update here with relevant changes.

Comment: I've updated the answer above. Can you check that once and let me know?